# how to create queue in android?

Tags: java, android, service

```
        Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null,null);
        int i=0;
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            Phone_no=cur.getString(2);
            Time=cur.getLong(4);
            Message_body=cur.getString(11);
            Date dateObj = new Date(Time);
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:ss");
            String Timenew = df.format(dateObj);
            Log.d(Tag,"INSIDE OF READ SMS INBOX");


           service.setClass(getBaseContext(), Background_Service.class);
           service.putExtra("Phone_no", Phone_no);
           service.putExtra("Message_body", Message_body);
           service.putExtra("Timenew", Timenew);
           getBaseContext().startService(service);
           }
```

the above code read the message from the inbox. And i send those message to the service for further processing. Is this the right way to do. Should i create a queue for the service execution, if so how to create, implement a queue to the above code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is applicable way.
But, i prefer another one.

Instead of starting a new service and routing new intents to it, you can create service once and bind to it, and send `Message`s to it.

First of all you need a messaging protocol. The easiest way it is create AIDL file with similar content.

```
package org.your.pkg;

interface IBackgroundService {
  void queueMsg(String phoneNo, String msgBody, String timeNew);
}
```

And then, you must implement it in your service.

```
class BackgroundService extends Service {

  IBackgroundService.Stub binder = new IBackgroundService.Stub() {
    public void queueMsg(String phoneNo, String msgBody, String timeNew) {
      // enqueue message to service thread. Do not process msg in this method.
    }
  };

  public IBinder getBinder() {
    return binder;
  }
}
```

And then, you must connect to your service.

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        IBackgroundService yourService = IBackgroundService.Stub.asInterface(service);

        // calls to yourService.queueMsg(...)
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Service has unexpectedly disconnected");
    }
};
```

There are more on [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) topic.